# "no records available" text disappears when new window pops up

Tags: winforms, telerik, telerik-grid, windows-controls

I am using Telerik WinForms UI controls, Version - "2016.2.503.40" (Telerik.WinControls).

Facing a weird issue with GridView control version - "2016.2.503.40" (Telerik.WinControls.GridView)

When data or records are not available on the grid I am showing "No records available" text using below code lines,

myGridView.TableElement.Text = "No records available";

which works fine below screen,

[image]

When some other window gets pop-up on this screen, "No records available" text disappears.

refer below screen,

[image]

No able to find out why the text is getting disappeared in such scenario.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Following the provided information, I have tried to replicate the problem with RadGridView from the Telerik UI for WinForms suite. Although a RadForm is shown over the main form, the expected "no data" text remains visible.

I would like to note that the appropriate way to localize any text in RadGridView is to use a RadGridLocalizationProvider. Thus, you can specify what text to be returned for the RadGridStringId.NoDataText. Please refer to the following help article demonstrating how to utilize the localization provider: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/localization/localization

However, if you are still experiencing any further difficulties, feel free to submit a support ticket from your Telerik account where you can provide a sample project demonstrating the issue you are facing.

I hope this information helps.

Comment: Thank you for providing the comments, I am going to check it and update you.